# Removing suspension from a bike

Tags: mountain-bike, touring, suspension

I'm looking to do a bit of light touring and want to outfit an old mountain bike to be up to the task. But most of the bikes I'm looking at have some crappy/mid-range suspension on them, which – to my understanding – only adds weight and an additional point of failure (at least from the perspective of touring).

What I'm wondering about is, **is it possible to buy a fixed fork for a bike and replace the suspension**?

If so, what sort of things should I watch out for?

Comment: Definitely doable - [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5459/how-do-i-choose-a-bicycle-fork) are the relevant measurements that you need to keep track of (along with the link that Vorac showed). You may want to get a bike shop to install the fork for you. [Park Tool](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/fork-column-length-and-sizing) also has some nice directions for setting up the fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be a problem. A decent Al-fork will easily replace a crappy 'suspension' fork. You'll just need to check for the right length and diameter of the stem and maybe replace the direction bearing as well.